# How to deploy Jetty-based web application

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jetty

I have implemented a jetty-based servlet under eclipse.It runs fine under eclipse. Right now, I need to deploy it as a Web application. I would like to know the procedures of transplanting these java programs from Eclipse to a real Jetty-based web application. The system is a Linux box. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export your Web Application as a WAR file in Eclipse and copy the WAR to:

```
/usr/share/jetty/webapps
```

(or appropiate path on your Linux box)

Restart the Jetty server and voila.

Comment: planetjones, I can not find the share directory under my root directory. Should I create it beforehand?

Comment: @bit-question well if you have Jetty installed you should have a webapps directory, it will be in $JETTY_HOME/webapps/, where the variable is the path where Jetty is installed on your system